# C++ Circular Dependencies

Tags: c++, include, circular-dependency

I am relatively new to C++, and I am trying to write a simple 2D engine. However, there is a problem with the current structure which was okay in other languages (AS3 etc). I have two classes, one called DisplayObject, and another one called DisplayObjectContainer. DisplayObjectContainer is a subclass of DisplayObject, but DisplayObject has a pointer to a DisplayObjectContainer parent as property. I can't figure out a way to properly include each other in their files. I can't forward declare DisplayObjectContainer in DisplayObject because I need to access DisplayObjectContainer's methods in DisplayObject.

DisplayObject:

```
class DisplayObject
{
    public:

        DisplayObjectContainer *parent;
...
    ...this->parent->globalTransform...
...
```

DisplayObjectContainer:

```
class DisplayObjectContainer : public DisplayObject
{
    public:
        DisplayObjectContainer();
        virtual ~DisplayObjectContainer();

    protected:

    private:
};
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: First, why does the parent class know about a specific derived class? Regardless, you'll need to use a forward declaration in the header containing `DisplayObject` (which will only have a `DisplayObjectContainer*` that is not dereferenced) and put the `include` in the source file (e.g., `DisplayObject.cpp`) for `DisplayObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to solve your problem, the simplest being to simply split up the `DisplayObject` into separate class and class-implementation. So you have the class defined in a header file, and the implementation of the member function in a separate source file.

That way the header file for `DisplayObject` don't need the header file for `DisplayObjectContainer`, all that's needed is the forward declaration of the `DisplayObjectContainer` class.

Something like this in the header file

```
#pragma once

// Forward declaration of the class
class DisplayObjectContainer;

class DisplayObject
{
private:
    DisplayObjectContainer *parent;
    ...
};
```

And in the source file you include the header files:

```
#include "DisplayObject.h"
#include "DisplayObjectContainer.h"

// Here you can use the members of DisplayObjectContainer
```

---

A harder way is to change the design so that `DisplayObject` doesn't actually need to know in which container it's stored. This decoupling is probably better in the long run, but like mentioned needs a redesign of your project.

Comment: Shouldn't this just be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: Thank you! The first suggestion solved the problem. For the second suggestion, I would consider redesigning it, although the structure I am following is the exact same structure Adobe Flash has.